# Redundant WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Question Background:**

I have a simple stored procedure that has been edited by another developer. They have added an AND clause to some SQL where before there was a WHERE clause. The developer is now insisting the AND and WHERE clause must both be present.

**The SQL:**

```
SELECT a.NOTIFICATIONID,
a.NOTIFICATIONTYPE,
a.DESCRIPTION,
b.NOTIFICATIONID,
b.SEEN,
b.SEEN_DATE,
b.PROFILEID
FROM dbo.NOTIFICATIONS a
LEFT JOIN dbo.NOTIFICATIONSTATUS b
ON a.NOTIFICATIONID = b.NOTIFICATIONID
AND b.PROFILEID = @profileId
WHERE (b.PROFILEID = @profileId or b.PROFILEID is null)
WHERE (b.DISMISSED = 0 or b.dismissed is null)
```

From what I can see the AND and WHERE clause are doing in effect the same work. The join will automatically filter down on the PROFILE_ID if there is a match and the WHERE clause will do the same thing.

Am I safe to assume that either the AND or the WHERE clauses are required, but not both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this `LEFT JOIN` case you can move the right side table's conditions to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT a.NOTIFICATIONID,
a.NOTIFICATIONTYPE,
a.DESCRIPTION,
b.NOTIFICATIONID,
b.SEEN,
b.SEEN_DATE,
b.PROFILEID
FROM dbo.NOTIFICATIONS a
LEFT JOIN dbo.NOTIFICATIONSTATUS b
ON a.NOTIFICATIONID = b.NOTIFICATIONID
 AND b.PROFILEID = @profileId 
 AND b.DISMISSED = 0
```

Comment: Many thanks, I miscopied the SQL so the b.PROFILE_ID field is no longer valid.

Comment: Do you mean `AND b.PROFILE_ID = @profileId ` should be removed?